# Customer: Website is not user friendly? Are there common rules or standards to do this?

Tags: asp.net, layout, user-friendly

We developed an asp.net website for one of our customer. We followed our rules and standards while building website. While showing it for customer, he said: it's not user friendly.

Are there common rules/standards for developing user friendly website?

Comment: What was he looking at when he said it? He could have meant that it wasnt accessibility friendly (see WCAG) or didnt validate (see W3C's validator). Those two messes up your site for screen readers and such.

Comment: I have never read it, but I have often heard "Don't make me think" quoted as the bible on this topic.

Comment: @Simon: Customer: I wasn't satisfied with website layout, leak user-friendly. So, I'm looking to know if there rules or standards we shall follow besides customer requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jakob Nielsen's "useit" site](http://www.useit.com/) is a great resource for web usability.

Comment: The books: 

- Designing Web Usability by Jakob Nielsen;

- Don't Make Me Think by Steve Krug;

 should be lectures for every Web devreloper.

Answer (score 0):

The [W3's Web Content Usability Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10/) make some interesting points from a technical perspective (Graceful degradation, device support, etc.) which can be useful bridge between techie and client.

Answer (score 0):

You'll obviously need an experience designer/information architext/usability expert. But before that I would ask your customer what aspects of the web site seem problematic. It's probably not **everything** wrong with it. It's probably just parts.

Three great books on this topic:

- [The elements of user experience](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-User-Experience-User-centered-Design/dp/0735712026/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247042656&sr=8-2) by Jesse James Garrett
- [Information architecture - blueprints for the web](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Information-Architecture-Blueprints-Christina-Wodtke/dp/0735712506/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247042748&sr=1-2) by Christina Wodtke
- [Don't make me think](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758/ref=pd_sim_b_1) by Steve Krug

Websites to consider:

- [Boxes and arrows](http://www.boxesandarrows.com/)
- [Adaptive path](http://adaptivepath.com/)